# Shell script to update the date (T ) with T+2 in a text file

Tags: shell-script

let say, the date appearing in text file at 4th position in DD-Mmm-YYYY format, I need to update the date T with T+2. if the day false on Thu or Fri then date should be replaced with T+4. ignore weekends.

I tried a script but my if condition is not working

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then echo "Usage: read.sh filename";
exit 1;
fi

while read line
 do
  echo $line
 olddate=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f4)
echo "olddate $olddate"
echo $(date -d $olddate +%a)
if [ "date -d $olddate +%a" = Thu ] || [ "date -d $olddate +%a" = Fri ]; then
newdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y -d "$olddate 4 day")
else
newdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y -d "$olddate 2 day")
fi
echo "newdate $newdate"
record=$(echo $line | sed "s|${olddate}|${newdate}|")
echo "new record $record"
done < $1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data. Both original and transformed values.

Comment: Possibly related - [unix shell script to update the date (T) appearing in file with T+2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416021/unix-shell-script-to-update-the-date-t-appearing-in-file-with-t2)

Comment: Define 'not working'.  How is it not working as you expect it to? What have you done to attempt to mitigate this?

Comment: Feed your code into https://shellcheck.net/ you'll get a number of errors that you need to fix. Including your `if` condition issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these two comparisons, you have given two strings which will always compare false, so they need to be replaced with a command substitution:

```
if [ "date -d $olddate +%a" = Thu ] || [ "date -d $olddate +%a" = Fri ]; then
    newdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y -d "$olddate 4 day")
else
    newdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y -d "$olddate 2 day")
fi
```

ie

```
today="$(date -d $olddate +%a)"
if [ "$today" = Thu ] || [ "$today" = Fri ]; then
    newdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y -d "$olddate 4 day")
else
    newdate=$(date +%d-%b-%Y -d "$olddate 2 day")
fi
```